# Configure Caliburn to automatically attach Loaded, Unloaded events

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have WPF application with Caliburn.Micro framework. I use often

`cal:Message.Attach="[Loaded] = [Load()]; [Unloaded] = [Unload()]"`

Is there any way to configure Caliburn to automatically look for `Load()`, `Unload()` methods in view models and bind them to the `Loaded`, `Unloaded` events if they exists?

(I know I can use `ViewAware.OnViewLoaded`, but there is no `OnViewUnloaded`. And beside that, using `cal:Message.Attach` the view model does not need to subclass `ViewAware`).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution with a help my colleague:

```
var caliburnBind = ViewModelBinder.Bind;
ViewModelBinder.Bind = (viewModel, view, context) =>
    {
        MyBinder.AddCustomBinding(viewModel, view);
        caliburnBind(viewModel, view, context);
    };
```

And the `MyBinder` class:

```
public static class MyBinder
{
    private const string LoadedEventName = "Loaded";
    private const string UnloadedEventName = "Unloaded";

    /// <summary>
    /// Automatically attach Loaded, Unloaded events.
    /// </summary>
    public static void AddCustomBinding(object viewModel, DependencyObject view)
    {
        if (view is FrameworkElement && viewModel is ViewModelBase)
        {
            EnsureLoading((ViewModelBase)viewModel, (FrameworkElement)view);
        }
    }

    private static void EnsureLoading(ViewModelBase model, FrameworkElement view)
    {
        Preconditions.CheckArgumentNotNull(model, "model");
        Preconditions.CheckArgumentNotNull(view, "view");

        Interactivity.TriggerCollection triggers = Interactivity.Interaction.GetTriggers(view);
        Ensure(triggers, view, LoadedEventName, ViewModelBase.LoadMethodName);
        Ensure(triggers, view, UnloadedEventName, ViewModelBase.UnloadMethodName);
    }

    private static void Ensure(Interactivity.TriggerCollection triggers, DependencyObject view, string eventName, string methodName)
    {
        if (IsEnsured(triggers, eventName, methodName))
            return; // already ensured

        string binding = string.Format("[{0}] = [{1}()]", eventName, methodName);
        triggers.Add(Parser.Parse(view, binding).Single());
    }

    private static bool IsEnsured(Interactivity.TriggerCollection triggers, string eventName, string methodName)
    {
        Interactivity.EventTrigger trigger = triggers.OfType<Interactivity.EventTrigger>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.EventName == eventName);
        if (trigger == null)
            return false;
        else
            return trigger.Actions.OfType<ActionMessage>().Any(a => a.MethodName == methodName && a.Parameters.Count == 0);
    }
}
```

This solution expects the view model subclass the ViewModelBase class, but may be easily changed to dynamically check for the `Load()`, `Unload()` methods.

Comment: I don't seen anything wrong with this solution, you could probably get away with dynamically setting `Message.Attach` rather that messing with the triggers to save yourself some code.